# Magento 2: is it possible to use a for loop in an x-magento-template?

Tags: magento2, javascript, template

Using 2.1.3, is there a way to iterate over an array in an `x-magento-template`?

i.e. (below is not working):

```
<script id="exampleTemplate" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <div>
       <p>Name: <%- data.name -%></p>
       <ul>
       <% for(var o in data.options) { %> 
          <li><%- data.options[o] -%></li>
       <% } %>
       </ul>
   </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmpl = mageTemplate('#exampleTemplate', {
                data: {
                  name: 'My product',
                  options: ['Option 1', 'Option 2']
               }
            });
    $(exampleContainer).append(tmpl);
</script>
```

To end up with:

```
<div>
     <p>Name: My product</p>
     <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you have any error in console? for example: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: @KAndy - yes:  'underscore.js:1442 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )(…)'.

Comment: Looks like you  don't need underscore at start `_for`

Comment: Thx @Kandy - I'm getting a different error on the `for` - there's some syntax I'm missing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved - I found this syntax in `vendor/magento/module-multiple-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/behavior.phtml`:

```
<script id="exampleTemplate" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <div>
       <p>Name: <%- data.name -%></p>
       <ul>
       <% _.each(data.options, function(item) { %> 
          <li><%- item.label -%></li>
       <% }); %>
       </ul>
     </div>
 </script>
```

And then convert the `data.options` to an array of objects:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmpl = mageTemplate('#exampleTemplate', {
            data: {
              name: 'My product',
              options: [
                 {label: 'Option 1'}, 
                 {label: 'Option 2'}
              ]
           }
        });
$(exampleContainer).append(tmpl);
```

Comment: Any idea how to do counter variable in this _.each loop? like the way we do i++ and all with PHP?

Comment: @VirangJethva pretty sure you can pass in an `index` as the 2nd arg to the `function()` call in the `_each` - ie, `<% _.each(data.options, function(item, index) { %> `

Comment: I know how to loop but want to have incremental variable inside loop. @dbcn

Comment: the value of `index` will increment starting from `0` @VirangJethva

Comment: Ohh my bad, sorry, I didn't look at that index param, thanks so much @dbcn.